# message queue в нескольких потоках

Tags: c++, boost

Использую очередь сообщений и столкнулся с проблемой.

Создаю очередь:

```
message_queue::remove("message_queue");
message_queue q(create_only             
    , "message_queue"                   
    , 100           
    , 100);
```

Далее пытаюсь в нескольких потоках  открыть очередь:

```
message_queue q(open_only, "message_queue");
```

И каждый из них выбрасывает исключение:

```
boost::interprocess_exception::library_error
```

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Что содержит текст исключения?

Comment: boost::interprocess_exception::library_error -- все что он содержит и ничего более

Comment: Не успевает ли объект `q` уничтожиться в потоке, где создается до момента открытия в другом потоке?

Comment: Попробуйте извлечь системной код ошибки при помощи get_native_error(), и искать уже его. И попробуйте сначала открывать очередь в одном потоке, чтобы точнее определить место возникновения проблемы.

Comment: Уничтожиться не успевает.

Попробую позже извлечь.

Comment: get_native_error() возвращает нуль.